Which suspense movie shows an Egyptian Freemasonry ceremony?
Drama or suspense movie, color, live-action, English-language, American or British production. Made between 1979-1985 (I viewed it on HBO circa 1986). Set in its own current day (late 1970s/early 1980s) in the middle east for most of the picture. British female lead (I thought it was Jane Seymour, but can't find it in her history on IMDB). She is researching some mystery, possibly a missing person, in the middle east. Her investigation leads her to the pyramids in Giza at one point. 
During one climactic scene she is running from a threat, bad guys in pursuit. They may have curved swords. As she flees in panic she recklessly bursts into a room where a secret society is in the middle of a Freemasonry-type ceremony. She is briefly surprised, but the participants continue their ritual motions, which adds to the eerie nature of the scenario. The participants are wearing white robes, and some may be wearing masks representing the ancient Egyptian gods (dogs, falcons, etc.). She then regains her wits and continues to flee out the opposite exit, figuratively one step ahead of her pursuers. 

The protagonist sounds very much like the one in Sphinx from 1981, but I don't think it featured that scene.

I remember watching a movie similar to this on HBO or Showtime in the mid-80s, but not since then. It was called The Awakening, and had Stephanie Zimbalist (from Remington Steel) as the female lead. It's set in Egypt, and has her and her father unraveling the mystery of whether she's possessed by an Egyptian spirit.
(I'd prefer to leave this as a comment, since it's a bit of a stretch, but I don't have the reputation to do so. Hopefully this won't result in an even lower reputation!)
